# DATAFLOW CalledProcessError returned non-zero exit status 2

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I'm trying to use Dataflow in the GCP. The contextualization is the following one.
-I have created a pipeline that works correctly in local. This is test.py document script: (I do a subprocess fonction which takes the script "script2.py" to be executed, script located in local and stored in a bucket in the cloud as well)

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions

 project ="titanium-index-200721"
 bucket ="pipeline-operation-test"
 class catchOutput(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self,element):
            import subprocess
            import sys
            s2_out = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "script2.py", "34"])
            return [s2_out]


def run():
    project = "titanium-index-200721"
    job_name = "test-setup-subprocess-newerr"
    staging_location = 'gs://pipeline-operation-test/staging'
    temp_location = 'gs://pipeline-operation-test/temp'
    setup = './setup.py'

    options = PipelineOptions()
    google_cloud_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).setup_file = "./setup.py"
    google_cloud_options.project = project
    google_cloud_options.job_name = job_name
    google_cloud_options.staging_location = staging_location
    google_cloud_options.temp_location = temp_location
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).runner = 'DataflowRunner'

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
    input = 'gs://pipeline-operation-test/input2.txt'
    output = 'gs://pipeline-operation-test/OUTPUTsetup.csv'

    results =(
      p|
      'ReadMyFile'>>beam.io.ReadFromText(input)|
      'Split'>>beam.ParDo(catchOutput())|
      'CreateOutput'>>beam.io.WriteToText(output)
   )
   p.run()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I have done a "setup.py" script for being able to include all the pakcages needed in future scripts to be also run in the dataflow of gcp.

Nevertheless when I try to run all that in the cloud, I'm having some problemsm to be more precise, when running the dataflow I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', 'script2.py', '34']' returned non-zero exit status 2 [while running 'Split']
```

I have tried placing the import call functions (subprocess,sys) in differents zones, I have also tried to modify the path of the script2.py which is in the bucket, but nothing has worked.

Finally one way to quit the error is by modifying the script with:

```
try:
    s2_out = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "script2.py", "34"])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    s2_out = e.output
```

But then my output is nothing. Because by doing that I only less the pipeline run but not to be correctly executed.

Anybody knows how could be this fixed?

Thanks you very much!

Guillem

Comment: before we trying to enumerate error cases, could you please check if you've included script2.py in the files to be staged? https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L620

Comment: Thanks you @ZhouYunqing . Nevertheless, I can't include a .sh file which is my goal. Theorically I can only add .py files

Comment: I mean if you are calling a py file from your job, you have to make sure the file exist on every worker. This is done by using the parameter I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks you! My question was if it is only possible to work with py files or I can use it for other language programming files?

Comment: That depends on what's available in the worker container. py is a safe choice because it is guaranteed to exist (because the worker itself is in py). Though I'm not sure if python is listed in PATH. You can examine the environment by logging into a VM and use docker command to attach the worker container. We do not guarantee what exists on the worker though.